# Comma usage after introductory adverb

Tags: commas

Is a comma needed in this sentence?

> There they search for an identity of their own.

Comment: Do you believe the comma changes the meaning?

Comment: A previous question here, 'In what circumstances can we omit commas when using adverbs at the beginning of a sentence?', was closed because no evidence of research had been given. However, Benjamin Harman's answer addresses this type of case (again, with not a lot of supporting evidence). But the thrust is that as 'there' connects to the previous sentence, the comma is optional.

Comment: This article from [GrammarTips](http://grammartips.homestead.com/adverbs2.html) addresses comma usage after introductory adverbs. << Often the introductory adverb modifies just the verb, as does the word "often" in this sentence. When that is the case, a comma is usually not necessary, but sometimes the writer may prefer to use the comma for emphasis or to create a dramatic pause. >>